# Factorization of the product of two specific primes

Tags: rsa, public-key, prime-numbers, factoring

Help me please.

Consider specific primes $p = x^{d} + 1$ and $q = x^{e} + 1$ for some $x, d, e \in \mathbb{N}$. Can their product $n = pq$ be factorized faster than the product of general primes ? In other words, is there a factorization algorithm that is more suitable for such $p$, $q$ than the state-of-the-art algorithms for primes of general form ?

Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In other words, is there a factorization algorithm that is more suitable for such $p, q$ than the state-of-the-art algorithms for primes of general form ?

If you know that $n$ is of the form $(x^d+1)(x^e+1)$, factorization should be trivial.

$n = x^{d+e} + x^d + x^e + 1 \approx x^{d+e}$ (unless either $x^d$ or $x^e$ is small).  We can easily scan through the possible values of $\sqrt[d+e]{n}$ for the various possible values of $d+e$, and find one that gives close to an integer value of $x$; that gives us $x$ and $d+e$; at this point, we know $n - (x^{d+e} + 1) = x^d + x^e$, from here, recovering $d$ and $e$ is easy.

And if (say) $x^d$ is small, then a simple search for small factors (either brute force or if you want to get fancy, ECM) will quickly find $x^d+1$

There are other strategies to factor an $n$ of this form - bottom-line: there are just too few possible values of $x, d, e$ to make this even slightly difficult.

Comment: poncho, thanks. What if $p = x^d + 1$, but $q$ is a general prime ?

Comment: @DimitriKoshelev: actually, all primes $p$ are in that form (with $d=1$ :-)

Comment: what if $x$ is small ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a supplement to poncho's answer.

Note that $n-1=x^{d+e}+x^d+x^e$ which is a multiple of $x^{\min(d,e)}$. Unless $x$ is large, it can easily be found by looking for small factors of $n-1$; next, how many times those small factors divide $n-1$, which should be $\min(d,e)$ times (except from the special case of $x=2$ and $d=e$).

This method is particularly effective for small $x$. And if it doesn't give a solution with small, or relatively small, value of $x$, you're in the setting where poncho's approach will be very effective.

Comment: Einar Rødland, thanks. What if $p = x^d+1$, but $q$ is a general prime ?

Comment: @DimitriKoshelev: You can let $d=1$, $x=p-1$, and there's no restriction on $p$. If $x$ is small, but $p$ is big, the possible values of $p$ are more limited. Can't immediately thing of anything better than trial-and-failure.